# Consume rest service using mobile service client in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to consume a service api with mobile service client with following block of code:

```
 MobileServiceClient mSClient;

    private async void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mSClient = new MobileServiceClient("https://XXXX.azure-mobile.net", "UFakeKkrayuAeVnoVAddgddcjYziYFSFHUV89");
        Dictionary<string, string> userobj = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        userobj.Add("UserName", txtuser.text);
        userobj.Add("Password", txtpass.text);
        userobj.Add("DeviceUID", "010092780200134E0300215F0400CC37050083D807006B9B080066010900267F");
        userobj.Add("DeviceToken", "device_123");
        userobj.Add("OSVersion", "WindowsPhone");
        userobj.Add("AppVersion", "2.0");
        userobj.Add("DeviceModel", "Windows phone");
        userobj.Add("DeviceTypeID", "1");
        userobj.Add("DeviceAlertsOn","true");      
        var responce= await mSClient.InvokeApiAsync("/user/loguserin", HttpMethod.Post, userobj);
     }
```

I am getting the following exception:

> An exception of type 
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException
>   occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code.

And Getting responce as following:

{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=05b093af5f4e7c6d198da2b2771de80c714f0499531fcab7ac6cc84e48dfeafc;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=chiefservices.azure-mobile.net
  Date: Wed, 27 Sep 2017 07:59:33 GMT
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 0
}}

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: A status code of 400 usually means that your request is malformed. If you have a request that is working, compare it to the one your application sends with e.g. fiddler.

Comment: Thanks larsbe for your reply, i am sorry to say this i am actually getting 404 responce not 400, i am just edited my post Can you please suggest me on this please

Comment: 404 means that you tried to access a resource that is not there. Usually your Url or the HTTP method is wrong.